# How to test message similarity for scheduled Facebook posts?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a web app that posts fb updates regularly for events every so many hours.  Whilst posting these to the fan page (which also uses the fb twitter share function), I get the following error back from the lib:

```
Facebook::APIError: OAuthException: (#100) The status you are trying to publish is a duplicate of, or too similar to, one that we recently posted to Twitter
```

The problem is that the message ARE indeed different and follow a pattern like:

- `#blah header: X some message here in the past Y hours. Stay tuned
  for further updates.`
- `#blah header: X some other message here have
  over the last Y hours. Stay with us for more updates.`

Are these messages *TOO SIMILAR* or is there something else at play here?  I'd think that the messages are different enough, however is there a way to test if messages are too similar and will be stopped by fb?

Comment: Are you sure there's not some kind of infinite loop at play - the status posted on facebook, then shared on twitter, and then - via some tool - brought back from twitter to facebook?

Comment: No, if I change the message up, it seems to send out without issue.  I have a feeling that this may be a Facebook bug.